# I am trying to find the complexity of this code

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
def f1(seq,thelast):
    for i in range(0,thelast):
        print(seq[i])

def f2(seq,thefirst,thelast):
    if thefirst==thelast:
        f1(seq,thelast)
    else:
        for i in range(thefirst,thelast):
            temp= seq[thefirst]
            seq[thefirst]=seq[i]
            seq[i]=temp
            f2(seq, thefirst+1, thelast)
            temp=seq[thefirst]
            seq[thefirst]=seq[i]
            seq[i]=temp
```

I have thought it has a for loop and a recursion and found it has complexity of O(n) but apperently it does not have this complexity. Am I missing something?

Comment: you have a loop (which would be `O(n)`) and inside you call the function recursively, making it `O(n2)`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Looks like more than *O(n^2)*, since it's being called recursively with `thefirst+1`. Could it be *O(n!)* ?

Answer (score 0):

You should solve the corresponding recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = n T(n-1) + c for n>1 (with T(1) = n)
```

Indeed you have `n` recursive calls with decreased input `n`. By iteration, you find it is `O(n*n!)`.

If you try simulating the code, you'll see it prints all permutations of seq that are `n!`. Printing the sequence has a cost of `n`. Hence you get `O(n*n!)`. You can verify it also by drawing the recursion tree.